Typescript: how do I make a function return a dynamic type based on passed parameters without directly defining the type?
I am trying to make a typescript function that would construct a dynamic type based on provided parameters. I know that the description is vague(it's hard for me to explain), but this is what I am working with:
get<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
    tableName: string,
    columns: K[] | '*',
    where?: (query: Knex.QueryBuilder) => void,
    trx?: Knex.Transaction
  ): Promise<Pick<T, K>[]> {
    let query = this.withTransaction(tableName, trx).select(columns);

    if (where) {
      where(query);
    }

    return query;
  }

type User = {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  role: Role;
  deleted: boolean;
};

This is how I would like to call the function:
const user = await this.db.get<User>(USER_TABLE_NAME, ['id', 'username', 'role']);
I am expecting for the type of user to be Pick<User, 'id' | 'username' | 'role'>[], but in reality it is Pick<User, keyof User>[]
What I am trying to achieve only works when I do get<T, K extends keyof T> instead of get<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>, but then I would need to call the function like this:
const user = this.db.get<User, 'id' | 'username' | 'role'>(USER_TABLE_NAME, ['id', 'username', 'role']);
I am unsatisfied with this outcome and am wondering if what I am trying to achieve even possible.

You can't. TS doesn't currently support partial type argument inference as requested in ms/TS#26242. Right now you have to work around it, such as with currying, as shown in this playground link (which I made random guesses about because the example here wasn't quite a [mre]).  See the linked q/a above for more info.
